# UICollectionViewCell can't set shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I want set shadow with `UICollectionViewCell`, like this:

[image: img]

I write code in Custom Cell

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.7176470757, green: 0.7176470757, blue: 0.7176470757, alpha: 1.0000000000).CGColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 4)
        layer.shadowRadius = 2
       layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    }
```

but can't set cell shadow. All subview by set shadow:

[image: mycell]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put clipsToBounds.That is the problem.

```
self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.7176470757, green: 0.7176470757, blue: 0.7176470757, alpha: 1.0000000000).CGColor
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 4)
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
self.clipsToBounds = false
self.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 1):

**Go to the collectionviewcell.m and add these manually.**

I did this to fix it.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //////// make shadow  of total view
        self.clipsToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;

        // make radius of the cell
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    }
    return self;
}
```

It will add effects and if you want to add some ui then code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line too:

```
layer.masksToBounds = false
```

By default it is `true` and limits the Cell within its frame size, by setting it to `false` allows cell's shadow to be visible outside its frame.

Comment: thanks, I added this line of code，but still the same, I checked the document.masksToBounds Defaults to NO